# How can I download an embedded RTF file from a web page?

Tags: download, rtf

I want to save the embedded RTF file on [this website](https://sites.google.com/site/professorleonard57/home/classes/calculus-1/test-review/test-1-review) to my computer, but can't figure out a way to do that. I tried to find the link to the file by opening its page source, but when the link there was for some reason broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When going to that page, you see it actually contains a `frame` to [https://docs.google.com/document/**preview**?hgd=1&id=1PrCg_1Y7OEQ9raTn_5LXQmq7c7DHTSvGPx-NOu3pOqM](https://docs.google.com/document/preview?hgd=1&id=1PrCg_1Y7OEQ9raTn_5LXQmq7c7DHTSvGPx-NOu3pOqM)

From there, we go to [https://docs.google.com/document/**edit**?hgd=1&id=1PrCg_1Y7OEQ9raTn_5LXQmq7c7DHTSvGPx-NOu3pOqM](https://docs.google.com/document/edit?hgd=1&id=1PrCg_1Y7OEQ9raTn_5LXQmq7c7DHTSvGPx-NOu3pOqM)

Then click File --> Download as --> {Choose your format}